# AJAX xmlhttp.open sumit data using POST method

Tags: javascript, post

I am trying to send a form data using POST method and xmlhttp.open
Please help find the error in my code

```
function submitChat() {
    if (form1.msg.value == '' ) {
        alert ('ALL FIELDS ARE MANDATORY');
        return;
    }

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var msg = form1.msg.value;
    var params = 'msg=helloooooooo';

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById('chatlogs').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open('POST', 'rtest.php?rid=14', true);
    xmlhttp.send(params);
}
```

Everything is fine and it is working with `GET` method. but `POST` method is not working. Please help.

Comment: That looks like it should work. What behaviour do you see and how does it differ from what you expect? Are there any messages in the Developer Tools Console of your browser? Have you used the Developer Tools Net tab to see what is going on?

Comment: It seems post data not being sent.  If i use GET  method it works fine.  I think there is something wrong with xmlhttp.open('POST','rtest.php?rid=14',true);
xmlhttp.send(params);

Comment: "It seems post data not being sent" — How are you determining this? Please answer the questions from my previous comment.

Comment: Ok.  I have rtest.php which saves the request data in my database.  So i have the code as $msg = $_REQUEST['msg'] :   and i save the value in my database.  When i use GET it saving the msg but with POST does not.  I am not familiar with developer console.

Comment: If you're writing JavaScript then you need to become familiar with it. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools / https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console